# Transferrring Data from an Excel Spreadsheet to Visual Basic

Tags: vba, excel, transfer

Hi there im having issues trying to transfer data from an excel spreadsheet to visual basic in the form of an array,any one know any reasonable means of doing so.I have searched online extensively but still cannot find a good tutorial on how to code it.

Simple step by step instructions with explanations would be appreciated as while im familiar with some parts of object orientated programming,I have never transferred data in this way.

Eventually I want to transfer this data onto an object orientated table with a few added buttons and functions thrown in

Cheers for any help guys

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.cpearson.com/excel/CollectionsAndDictionaries.htm (range to collection or dictionary)?  I think the principles of what you are looking for are there.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to customise the following code:

```
examplerange = workbooks("Workbook 1").worksheets("Sheet 1").range("A1:B17")
```

where `Workbook 1` is the name of the workbook that you are using (minus the extension, e.g. '.xlsx'), `Sheet 1` is the name of the worksheet the range is located and `A1:B17` is the range in which you wish to import.

This creates a `Variant` array-which is inefficient-however this is an easy way to import data into VBA and acceptable if you are not working with large sets of data.

Once you're more familiar, you'll be able to separate the elements in the code above and iterate through dynamic ranges as well as being able to import string / integer / boolean arrays to reduce memory usage.

Hope this is what you're looking for.